# Tilde (~) shortcut in chroot jail

Tags: linux, ssh, chroot

I have set up a chroot jail with bash for an ssh user. The "true" path of the home directory is `/home/jails/home/name`, and the chroot directory is `/home/jails`. When the tilde `~` shortcut is used in the bash, however, it tries to take the user to `/home/jails/home/name`, which does not exist inside the jail. If I change the home directory to simply `/home/name`, then the ssh fails to look up the `authroized_keys` file. What are my options?

Comment: Looks like some interesting detail on [this page](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/)